# Ant: How to set the different value to a property depending on user's input

Tags: ant

I am taking user's input using below input task:

```
<input message="Select the provisioning profile to be used for packaging i.e. old or new" addproperty="provProfileSelected" validargs="o,n" defaultvalue="o" />
```

Then, I want to set different values to one property depending on the the user's input. I am able to get the user's input. But how to conditionally set the value to the property?

I don't want to use Antt-Contrib in my build script.

Comment: The problem that you may run into is that properties are immutable - so once set - you can't change the value, but generally you don't get any type of warning - the value just stays whatever the initial value was.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that might work for you.  You save the input into one property, then conditionally you set additional properties based the response.  You use up 2 extra properties but shouldn't be a problem.  old and new targets will be conditionally executed based on the existence of the new property.

Hope this helps!

```
<project name="testing" basedir="." default="all">

<target name="all" depends="input, old, new"/>

<target name="input">
    <input message="Select the provisioning profile to be used for packaging i.e. old or new"  addproperty="provProfileSelected" validargs="o,n" defaultvalue="o" />
    <echo>${provProfileSelected}</echo>
    <condition property="newSelected">
        <equals arg1="n" arg2="${provProfileSelected}"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="oldSelected">
        <equals arg1="o" arg2="${provProfileSelected}"/>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="new" if="newSelected">
    <echo>New provisioning selected</echo>
</target>

<target name="old" if="oldSelected">
    <echo>Old provisioning selected</echo>
</target>

</project>
```